# How to determine a full path of a named folder?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to determine the full path of certain folders. In my array, I just have the names of the folders, but when my application will get installed on another user's machine, my program must be able to determine the full-path of these folders.

How to get the fullpath?

Comment: Can you describe the format of the folder name you're storing, and what you expect them to be relative to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean the My Documents folder and the rest? It's not obvious for me from your question.

The My Documents folder is:

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

And the rest of the special system folders can be retrieved in a similar way.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the method `Path.GetFullPath`, it could be useful to what you're trying to do.

[Path.GetFullPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

Comment: Definitely easiest. Note that it uses the *current path*, not necessarily the path the executable is running in (while most of the times, that will the same).

Answer (score 4):

By prefixing it with another Path. Which Path depends on your application.

```
string path = ...
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, folderNames[i]);
```

You could take a look at `Environment.GetFolderPath(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me that you mean actually the *current path plus an additional path*. I.e., suppose your application is installed in `c:\installations` and you need the relative path of `resource\en-US`, you want to find `c:\installations\resource\en-US`.

Normally I would go for getting the [current path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx), but in Windows it is possible to start an application as if it is executing from a different path. A fool-proof way of getting the path of the current application (where it is installed) is as follows:

```
// gets the path of the current executing executable: your program
string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

// transform it into a real path...
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);

// ...to make it easier to retrieve the directory part
string currentPath = info.Directory.FullName;
```

Now it becomes trivial to get new paths.

```
string someRelativePath = @"reource\en-US";
string someFullPath = Path.Combine(currentPath, someRelativePath);
```

I know, it looks a bit contrived, but it is safer then using the [current path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[FileInfo.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx), if you are lucky and the constructor finds your file somehow (e.g. current working directory).